# Python module "trace": file path missing

Tags: python, trace

I am tracing a python script like this:

```
python -m trace --ignore-dir=$HOME/lib64:$HOME/lib:/usr -t bin/myscript.py
```

Some lines look like this:

```
 --- modulename: __init__, funcname: getEffectiveLevel
__init__.py(1325):         logger = self
__init__.py(1326):         while logger:
__init__.py(1327):             if logger.level:
__init__.py(1329):             logger = logger.parent
__init__.py(1326):         while logger:
__init__.py(1327):             if logger.level:
__init__.py(1328):                 return logger.level
```

Unfortunately I have no clue where this code comes from.

Is there a way to see the file name (including the path) of `getEffectiveLevel()`?

Of course I could search through all installed python code for a method with this name, but I would like to see the file path immediately.

In this context **Python 2.7** gets used.

> I am not fixed to the standard library "trace". I could use a different library, if it provides the needed feature.

Comment: checked https://python-hunter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ?

Comment: @IAmBatman thank you very much for your comment. The hunter lib looks good. If you write it as answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: added it as an answer, I hope someone will find it useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the purpose is finding the full path, then check [hunter](https://python-hunter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#id1) project, it even has support for [query-style](https://python-hunter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html) tracing.

```
# a modified example from docs
# do check the documentation it is easy to start with
from hunter import trace, Q, Debugger
from pdb import Pdb

trace(
    # drop into a Pdb session on``myscript.mainMethod()`` call
    Q(module="myscript", function="getEffectiveLevel", kind="call", action=Debugger(klass=Pdb)))

import myscript
myscript.mainMethod()
```

Comment: Thank you very much this software recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no flag/command-line option to enable that. So the immediate (and probably correct) answer is: **No**.

If you're okay with messing with the built-in libraries you can easily make it possible by changing the line that reads:

```
print (" --- modulename: %s, funcname: %s" 
       % (modulename, code.co_name))
```

with:

```
print ("filename: %s, modulename: %s, funcname: %s"
       % (filename, modulename, code.co_name))
```

in the `trace.py` file of your Python installation. You can find the path to that file with:

```
>>> import trace
>>> trace.__file__
```

But I really don't want to suggest that modifying libraries that way is something I would recommend. Before you do this (if you decide you really want to do that) create a backup of the file and if possible replace it again after you're done.

A better way (although still messy) is to copy the above mentioned `trace.py` file (for example into the current working directory) and modify the copied file. Then you can run the modified version:

```
python path_to_modified_trace_file your_options_for_trace
```

Without the `-m` option and with the modified path, but otherwise identical to your original.

Comment: I am not fixed to the standard library "trace". I could use a different library, if it provides the needed feature.

Comment: @guettli In that case you probably need to specify which functionality should be included. It's not hard to write a trace-function yourself (with very limited capabities) but it becomes really complex if you have "complicated needs".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `trace2.py` file with below content

```
from trace import Trace, main

original_globaltrace_lt = Trace.globaltrace_lt

def patch_Trace_globaltrace_lt(self, frame, why, arg):
    value = original_globaltrace_lt(self, frame, why, arg)
    if value:
        filename = frame.f_globals.get('__file__', "")
        print("The code is in file - %s" % (filename))
    return value

Trace.globaltrace_lt = patch_Trace_globaltrace_lt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and then run it like below

```
python -m trace2 --ignore-dir=$HOME/lib64:$HOME/lib:/usr -t bin/myscript.py
```

The output is verbose but you can alter the function `patch_Trace_globaltrace_lt` as per your needs